# localStorage redirect when fresh page is loaded

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create a localStorage for one of my pages, so the user doesn't have to submit their selected `GET` forms all the time when they load the webpage.

I've made two variables `url` (current url) and `defaultUrl` (url without parameters (not used atm)), then i thought that I should set the localStorage when the user closes the tab/page by running `window.onbeforeunload`. But how should I create the redirect? Because right now it loops... And I don't know how to do this properly

```js
var url = location.href; //Current page
var defaultUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname; //without parameters

//When page is closed
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return localStorage.setItem("url", url);
};

//If local storage is set then load it? BUT HOW? Loops right now...
if (localStorage.getItem("url") !== null) {
    var oldUrl = localStorage.getItem("url");
    localStorage.removeItem("url");
    window.location.replace(oldUrl);
}
```

**Edit**

I've managed to create a solution for my problem, with some help from you guys.

```js
//LocalStorage saves/redirects to url
var url = location.href; //Current page
var defaultUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname; //without parameters

//If the user access the default webpage url then redirect (Only if localStorage isn't default page for some reason)
if (url === defaultUrl) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("url") !== null) {
        var oldUrl = localStorage.getItem("url");
        localStorage.removeItem("url");
        if (oldUrl !== defaultUrl) {
            window.location.replace(oldUrl);
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("url", url);
    }
} else {
    //If the user followed a link to the webpage or made a GET request then save this for later
    localStorage.setItem("url", url);
}

//All GET submits should have this class, due to it resets the LocalStorage so it's ready to be set again on reload
$(document).on('click', '.formClickResetUrl', function(event) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("url") !== null) {
        localStorage.removeItem("url");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) is deprecated.

When it is working, your code effectively keeps "url" key in `localStorage`. After you `removeItem`, it navigates to `oldUrl`, `onbeforeunload` is triggered, "url" is added again.

Try following without `onbeforeunload`

```
if (localStorage.getItem("url") !== null) {
    var oldUrl = localStorage.getItem("url");
    localStorage.removeItem("url");
    window.location.replace(oldUrl);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("url", url);
}
```

Revised:

```
var url = location.href; //Current page

if (location.search.length === 0) { // url without parameters, the default page (i suppose)
    if (localStorage.getItem("url") !== null && localStorage.getItem('defurl')) {
        var oldUrl = localStorage.getItem("url");
        window.location.replace(oldUrl);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('defurl', true); // visited the default page
} else if (!localStorage.getItem('defurl')) { // someone copy/paste a url with parameter, redirect to default page
    window.location.replace(location.pathname);
} else {
    //If the user followed a link to the webpage or made a GET request then save this for later
    localStorage.setItem("url", url);
}
```

click event handling is not required.

Revised 2, no redirect for url with parameters

```
var url = location.href; //Current page

if (location.search.length === 0) { // url without parameters, the default page (i suppose)
    if (localStorage.getItem("url") !== null) {
        var oldUrl = localStorage.getItem("url");
        window.location.replace(oldUrl);
    }
} else {
    //If the user followed a link to the webpage or made a GET request then save this for later
    localStorage.setItem("url", url);
}
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this now, is IF I submit a GET on the page, to maybe show somthing else on the page, then it redirects me back to the old page, so all GET methods doesn't work for the page now.

Comment: I suppose you want to stay on the page before the user submits one or probably a few GET requests, after that, it redirects. Then it is not suitable to save a single "url" in localStorage. You probably need to attach an event listener to user's GET request, and save to localStorage that GET X is made.  Then you can check if GET X, Y Z are made then do the redirect.

Comment: I'm actually doing something like this right now :)  I just choose to remove the local storage when a submit `GET` is made, then your code just creates a new url in LocalStorage, and when the page then is reopened, then that old page is loaded

Comment: Only thing I'm trying to solve now is what to do if someone copy paste a url, then it shouldn't redirect them away from that

Comment: someone new paste the url to open the page, `localStorage.getItem("url")` is null, it won't redirect. anything wrong with my understanding?

Comment: I will create an edit with my working solution :)

Comment: I've created it now, if you have anything to change to it, then edit your solution and I will approve it, since I couldn't have done it without your help

Comment: see revised. you visit a.html -> a.html?param=1, next time you open a.html redirect to a.html?param=1; someone else paste and visit a.html?param=1, redirect to a.html

Comment: Not really, what I did is:  user goes to `webside (url)` makes a GET submit and then goes to `website (url?paramA)`, user now closes `website (url?paramA)` and opens the regular `webside (url)`, but then the user will be redirected to `website (url?paramA)`. BUT if the user didn't open the regular `webside (url)` but instead `website (url?paramB)` then he won't get redirected to `website (url?paramA)`, since another user could have sent him a link to look at, so it wouldn't make sense to direct him away from this page, and if he closes this page, he will be redirected to `website (url?paramB)`